# Db Design: Junction table or column

Tags: database-design

I have three tables like below.

```
user        company     user_company
--------    -------     ------------------
id(pk)      id(pk)      user_id(pk, fk)
                        company_id(pk, fk)
```

My problem is: Each **user** and **company**, must have a unique *customer number*. And I want to connect these **user** and **company** tables to single table.

So, should I create junction tables for **user** and **company**?

```
customer            user_customer           company_customer
---------------     ------------------      ----------------
customer_no(pk)     user_id(pk, fk)         company_id(pk, fk)
customer_type       customer_no(pk, fk)     customer_no(pk, fk)
```

Or should I just add id column to **customer** table?

```
customer
---------------
customer_no(pk)
user_id(fk)
company_id(fk)
```

Which one is correct? Or, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I'd keep it simple and just add the id to the customer table unless you have a very good reason not to.